# How can I access chrome.history from a Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-worker

Is there any way I can access the chrome.* apis (specifically `chrome.history`) from a Web Worker?

If I pass the chrome.history or chrome object in with `postMessage`, it is not working because of a conversion error to `Transferable` type.

I can successfully query the history from my extension and pass the results, but I would like to leave the heavy lifting to the worker instead of the main thread and then pass the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Workers are meant to be light-weight, and do not inherit any permissions ([not even host permissions](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45382)) from the extension (besides, `chrome` is not even defined in a Web worker).

If you're doing really heavy stuff with the results of the `chrome.history` API, then you could pass the result of a callback to a worker for processing (with Transferables, the overhead is minimal). Before doing that, make sure that you profile whether the performance impact is really that significant to warrant implementing anything like this.

Comment: Thanks @Rob W, I have implemented a callback handle for the worker and it is working nicely. I am querying 8000+ items in my history (which is pretty quick) but I wanted to hand that processing off to the worker (as opposed to just handing it the results). I suspect someone wanting a history management plugin has a lot of items as well.

Comment: @click2install The Chrome extension API is asynchronous, designed to be non-blocking. Because of this, there's hardly any difference between querying the history from the main thread and passing the result to a worker vs somehow querying the history from the worker thread.

Comment: totally agree. I did have the code in the override page (which caused < 1 sec lag). I have sinced moved it to `background.js` which has no page and it's working nicely.