# How to access Chrome API in Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, web-worker, chrome-app-developer-tool

I have some `metadataWorker.js` in my Chrome App, It is Web Worker and runs as follows:

```
metaThread = new Worker('/src/utils/metadataworker.js');
```

But I can't access the `chrome` global object in `metadataworker.js`.

Is there any way to use Chrome API (access the `chrome` global object) in Web Worker?

Comment: Try using a Chrome Worker ! -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChromeWorker

Comment: I hear first time about it, can you provide some documentation?

Comment: But this examples for firefox, they not working on chrome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216481/how-can-i-access-chrome-history-from-a-web-worker

Comment: Well, that sucks!! Why can't I do heavy operation in a different worker?
Or even, operations that require a different thread...

Answer (score 3):

You can't access chrome object from web worker. This is sandboxed from the app and it run in separate thread. You can only use web APIs inside a web worker, without DOM access.